# Excel crashes after triggering macro by clicking a cell

Tags: vba, excel

As the title mentions, the macro crashes after clicking a cell to trigger it. I have used this for 2 months with no crashes or other problem but it crashes all the time today. Then, I tried to run the macro by calling the same function in the Immediate Window and it ran properly. I am wondering why and how to solve this.

For your reference, here is my code in that worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
    reviewActiveSheetOrder

End If

End Sub
```

`reviewActiveSheetOrder` is the function I want to run, and it can run properly if I call it in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: On which line does it crash?

Comment: Agreed that we need to see the error, probably also need to see the code for reviewActiveSheetOrder as the issue might be in there and bubbling up to the top.

Comment: but it can run properly when I call it in the immediate Window, so I think the code is not important?

Comment: what is stack trace?

Comment: If the crash is occurring on a line within `reviewActiveSheetOrder` then the code for `reviewActiveSheetOrder` will be **very** important if you want us to help you.  But if the crash is occurring on the `If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then` line then, I agree, the code for `reviewActiveSheetOrder` probably won't be important.  So where is it crashing?

Comment: when I click on it, it will run through the reviewActiveSheetOrder 
but crash at last

Comment: the strange thing is no crash will occur when I call it in immediate window

Comment: What do you mean "crash at last"?  Is it highlighting the `End Sub` of the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` procedure?  Or somewhere else? And what error message are you getting?

Comment: The error message is excel stopping responding/running sth like that

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `reviewActiveSheetOrder` line and then single-step through the code.  What line is the last one executed before it crashes.  (And perhaps, before you try that, try rebooting your computer just to make sure nothing is corrupt in memory.)

Comment: I have reboot the computer but same thing occurs, because quite strange as I could run it in immediate window , but crash when I trigger it by clicking a cell

Comment: I just tried to put a stop/pause at the line End Sub, then click the cell to trigger the macro,  the macro does not crash

Comment: But if I remove the stop and click to run the macro again, it crashes

Comment: The pop up with Excel has stopped working appears

Comment: Do you disable Events within `reviewActiveSheetOrder`? I am thinking that `reviewActiveSheetOrder` makes changes which triggers other events etc causing endless loop. It will be much easier if you post it's code.

Comment: What code you have for `reviewActiveSheetOrder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable events before calling `reviewActiveSheetOrder` and see if that helps...

Also place `Cancel = True` before calling another procedure as after double clicking a cell, you are in the `Edit Mode`, maybe that is causing the issue.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    reviewActiveSheetOrder
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it did not crash after adding that 3 lines of code but seems it does not run the marco

it also fine if I only add the line "cancel = True" but again, the macro seems not working

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't pause the code before it was completed as the events would not be enabled again in that case. To check if the events are enabled, in the `Immediate Window`, type `?Application.EnableEvents` and hit `Enter`. What you get, a `True` or `False`? If you get `False`, you will need to enable it again manually and to do so type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate Window and hit Enter and then double click A2 to see if the code runs this time. Also place a `Breakpoint` at the line Application.EnableEvents = True to see if the code gets there after completion.